# Aligning output to the terminal using C++

Tags: c++, terminal

I am having a lot of trouble aligning my output to the terminal. I want to print a vector of vectors viz `vector< vector<double>  >  myvec;` to the output where myvec[i] occupies the ith row on the terminal. The vectors composing `myvec` have size 3

This is  the way I am trying to print it.

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i<myvec.size() ; ++i   )
{


cout<<myvec[i][0]<<"     "
    <<myvec[i][1]<<"     "
    <<myvec[i][2]<<'\n';
}
```

When I print this to output only the myvec[i][0] column of numbers is aligned properly. The rest of the numbers look messy. Is there a good way to align this output? 
(Ignore the 0.7 printed to the right on line 5 of image)

[image]

Comment: Use tabs (\t) instead of spaces "   " between the columns.

Comment: We really needed a physical screenshot for this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setw()` to set the minimum number of characters you want to be written and `left` to output the data to the left. Like this:

```
cout << setw(8) << left << myvec[i][0];
```

This should fill the empty space with spaces but if not, then you can do:

```
cout << setw(8) << left << setfill(' ') << myvec[i][0];
```

You will need to `#include <iomanip>` for this.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked nicely for me. One question one the working of setw() though. Say myvec[i][0] has value 2.71828 and I do `cout << setw(3) << left << myvec[i][0];` does that mean only 2.7 will be printed to the output?

Comment: @GaurishTelang No. `setw()` sets the *minimum* number of characters to be written.

Comment: Any command to set maximum number of characters to be written?

Comment: Also, you have to insert `setw()` every time, as it's not persistent. (And `setprecision()` is the answer to your question.)

Comment: @GaurishTelang As Kerrek said.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple notes about your code:

## Alignment types

quasiverse's answer gives you left justification, i.e. every number starts in the first character position. Drop the `left` to make it right-justify, i.e. every number starts in the last character position.

Aligning the decimal points is a bit harder. If you want to set a fixed number of digits past the decimal point, then replace the `left` with `fixed` and add `setprecision()`, giving it the number of digits you want past the decimal. For example, to show two digits past the decimal:

```
cout << setw(8) << fixed << setprecision(2) << myvec[i][0];
```

## 2-D Vectors

You're declaring `vector< vector<double> > myvec;`, but the minor (second) dimension appears hardcoded to 3. This means that you are creating a vector of vectors, where each row is an entire vector object with storage for three doubles.

`vector`s don't store their data internally; the actual vector object just stores the number of elements, a pointer to the actual data storage, and maybe a couple other things. The actual data is stored in a separate block. This will create a lot of overhead and memory fragmentation (every row allocates a block to store the data).

For example, for a 1000x3 vector, there is the top-level vector object on the stack, an array of 1000 vector objects (one per row) on the heap, and each of those points to a block of three doubles, so you have 1001 objects on the heap and every access has to go through two pointers. Slow and inefficient.

`vector` is overkill if the length is fixed. So I'd recommend having a vector of structures, with each structure having three doubles:

```
struct point {
    double x, y, z;
};
vector<point> myvec;
```

This stores all the data in one block, since `point` is completely self-contained.  Then your code is:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < myvec.size() ; ++i)
{
    cout << setw(8) << left << myvec[i].x << ' ' << setw(8) << left << myvec[i].y 
        << ' ' << setw(8) << left << myvec[i].z << endl;
}
```

Or, the C++ iterator way to do it:

```
for(vector<point>::const_iterator elem = myvec.begin(); elem != myvec.end() ; ++elem)
{
    cout << setw(8) << left << elem.x << ' ' << setw(8) << left << elem.y 
        << ' ' << setw(8) << left << elem.z << endl;
}
```

This saves a bunch of calls to `operator[]`. If your compiler supports the new C++11 standard, you can change the `for()` line to:

```
for(auto elem = myvec.begin(); elem != myvec.end() ; ++elem)
```

where `auto` tells the compiler to make `elem` the same type as what `myvec.begin()` returns. Another C++11 way, less likely to be supported, is the [range-based for loop](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html):

```
for(auto elem: myvec)
```